# Method Overloading per address-space qualifiers on 'this' parameter

Tags: c++, embedded, clang++, address-space, language-extension

In C++ using clang++, is it possible to overload a method according to address-space qualifiers on the implicit ‘this’ parameter?   If so, what is the syntax?

[This source](https://www.codeplay.com/portal/impact-of-address-spaces-on-c) suggests that I can place the address-space qualifier after the parameter list but before the curly braces (*similar to using the const qualifier on 'this'*).  I tried the following, but **it failed**; clang thinks I'm trying to set an address space of the method, rather than of 'this':

```
 // Does not work.
 struct SomeClass
 {
   // method for 'this' in default address space
   void doit();
   // method for 'this' in address space 300.
   void doit() __attribute__((address_space(300)); // clang rejects this syntax
 }
```

The closest I have found is that clang lets me overload a method according to the address spaces of its explicit formal parameters (**not 'this'**). For example, the code below will print “1\n2\n”.

```
// Similar, but does not solve my problem:
#include <cstdio>

struct SomeClass
{
  void doit(void *v)     { printf("1\n"); }
  void doit(void __attribute__((address_space(300))) *v) { printf("2\n"); }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  SomeClass SC;

  SC.doit( (void*) 0 );
  SC.doit( (void __attribute__((address_space(300))) *) 0 );

  return 0;
}
```